# Spansion Nor Flash Offset and base address

Tags: c, nor

I am getting stuck on understanding the idea of offset and base address to read and write to NOR flash from Spansion/cypress.

Can someone help me by providing example in c or c++ OF simple read and write operation on embedded nor flash?

Comment: The idea is that `Address = base + offset`

Comment: thank you for the reply @Eugene. I got that part, but What i did not understand is how should i assign the offset value, since the documentation says offset is length in word(2bytes). I have been struggling to read and write with the chip for a week now. can you please give a snippet of code which might give me insight how the addressing reading and writing works.